# storing bike outside - avoiding trapped moisture and rainfall (bike covers)

Tags: maintenance, storage, rain

I just got a specialized tricross for riding in the city and going on short tours around Europe.

Unfortunately I don't have enough space in the corridor of the house so I will have to put it outside in the garden. In the UK we have a lot of precipitation so I want to get a good bike cover. I was wondering if anyone can recommend me a special kind of material or brand for a cover. I know that one of the main issues is condensation so I guess it needs to be a breathable material.

Is the Oxford Aquatex any good, does anyone have experience with this model or with the brand in general?

Any suggestions welcome! I want to take good care of my baby... :)

Comment: Just don't be guilty of [this](http://www.theonion.com/articles/cruel-owner-chains-bike-outside-in-freezing-weathe,31593/)

Comment: (This issue has been covered (cough) before.  There is at least one good "duplicate question" out there.  The gist, though, is to cover with a reasonably waterproof tarp, but not wrap too tightly, so that air can circulate through the open bottom.)

Comment: Possible duplicates:  http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/how-to-store-a-bike-outside-and-still-avoid-rapid-decay?rq=1 and http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/6181/how-to-store-bicycles-outside-during-winter?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this question hasn't been closed as a duplicate yet, I'll point to two answers from another question: [How to store a bike outside and still avoid rapid decay?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/1120/3649)

First, you can use a tarp as described here: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/9192/3649

Second, you can use a shed which you could put in your garden:
https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/1122/3649

Answer (score 3):

You know, I worry that marketing firms have brainwashed the entire world into believing that you need to spend a lot of money on fancy materials that are waterproof and breathable. Honestly, just spend a few pounds on a [poly tarp](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0053QUAAG) and your bike will stay as dry as the day you bought it. Just be sure that you take the bike out to give it some fresh air each day so that you don't have to worry about condensation building up and causing problems. You'd still have to do this anyway even if you bought something expensive, no matter how breathable the salesman promised you it would be.

Comment: Yep, probably better to avoid something advertised as "breathable", as it will be less waterproof.

Comment: ok, thanks. I won't spend that much then on a cover.