# Storing a nice bike outside cheaply in the city during winter (weather/security)

Tags: winter, frugal, weather, theft, protection

I'm no longer able to store bicycles in my flat, as my current place is less than 20m² in size; Is there any way to store a bicycle outside in a way which will significantly minimize **weather**- and **crime**-related damage/loss?

The said (two) bikes are nice enough to sell for a decent amount of money, and so they're not throw-away "supermarket trip" bikes and they are rather pretty (i.e. they stick out to thieves). Selling them (for a decent price) will take quite some time, but time is not on my side:

1. Eventually, someone will either steal them or try to steal them (damaging them in the process), regardless of how massive the lock on them is
2. The weather will eventually damage them, anyway: Where I am, we can get to -10° C/14° F and have a wonderful amount of snow-plus-rain-turned-ice-turned-muddy-slush. E.g. a [shed](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/1122/8685) is not an option: I cannot (i.e. am not allowed to) build or buy any kind of free-standing things to put them under, and I assume that a [tarp](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/9192/8685) will get stolen or at least torn quite quickly (I've already had one stolen in the space of a few years).

Comment: Do you plan to ride the bikes any time soon? If not could you store them with a friend or relative who might have more available space?

Comment: Is renting indoor storage space an option?

Comment: @ilikeprogramming, I will ride them regularly, but at least one will always be there (because I can't take the other one with me), so getting "rid" of one temporarily is definitely an improvement.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, yes, renting some storage space is the option I'm going for if I don't find a cheaper solution here.

Comment: Metal doesn't decay as long as you lube them. For expensive bikes, just hang it on your ceiling, or rent a small space from your neighbor that willing to do so.

Comment: Consider that given your space availability, 2 bikes is too many.  Consider buying a smaller folder, or using rental bike schemes until your situation improves.

Comment: @Criggie, definitely-- maybe I should write an additional question, titled "how do I literally downsize my bicycle collection?" ;)

Comment: This video may help you out: [Wall ceiling bike rack under $50](https://youtu.be/-Xjmvk3-LXI)

Comment: Not allowed to drill, sorry...

Comment: Removing the pedals and turning the bar by 90° will make any bike very flat, If you remove the front wheel and fix it to the frame one the drive-side you will shorten the overall length by 30-40cm at least and you won't need to alter the position of the bar.

Comment: There are also posts that extend from floor to ceiling, keeping in place through pressure alone and where you can suspend two bikes one above each other.

Comment: Pack the bikes into bike boxes and stash the boxes somewhere (under the bed for example). If you're going to ride one regularly, just do as you normally do for storing the bikes (outside) -- bringing a bike in in cold weather is asking for more problems than it solves. Get renters insurance to cover potential theft.

Comment: And you can get an old bike to beat around for the winter.